# How to filter and read values and keys out of a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, filter

i am currently working on a python script which in theory should read me a YAML File (hostname_list) and save the contents as a nested dictionary (called the same). In the next step it should loop over the all the keys of the second dictionary (see example below) and check in the third dictionary for the key "severity" and if the key has certain a value given in a parameter at the beginning. If that parameter is the same as the value in that certain dictionary it should print the key of the second dictionaty aswell as all the keys and values of the third dictionary in a json format into the console.

my dictionary:

```
{"sap_landscape":  #dict1
                 {"dctr1440":  #dict2
                            {"hostname": "dctr1440", "SID": "TT", "Type": "Spo",  #dict3
                            "Landscape": "RFK", "Severity": "SX", "Username": "adm", 
                            "UserID": 93, "Global": null, "Cycle": 1}, 
                 "dctr1091": {"hostname": "dctr1091", "SID": "TT", "Type": "Spo", "Landscape": 
                             "RFK", "Severity": "SX", "Username": null, "UserID": null, 
                             "Global": null, "Cycle": 2}, 
                 "dctr1512": {"hostname": "dctr1512", "SID": "TT", "Type": "C", 
                              "Landscape": "RFK", "Severity": "SBX", "Username": null, 
                              "UserID": null, "Global": null, "Cycle": 1}, 
                 "dctr193": {"hostname": "dctr193", "SID": "TT", "Type": "I", "Landscape": 
                              "RFK", "Severity": "SX", "Username": null, "UserID": null, 
                              "Global": null, "Cycle": 2}
```

the code i have written so far:

```
def main(severity):
with open(filename) as infile:
    hostname_list = yaml.safe_load(infile)

for k in hostname_list['sap_landscape'].keys():           # i don't know if that is correct 
    for s in hostname_list['sap_landscape'][k].items():     since i am clueless what to do 
                                                            after i read the file and saved it 
                                                            as a dict
```

sorry if that's not a lot to work with but i am very new to python and struggling with dictionaries quite much. if you have a solution and got a little bit of time it would be nice if you could write a short description how/why you were doing it the way you did since i want to learn from my mistakes.

thanks in anvance :)

Comment: Please share the exact result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it can be done:

```
for k1, v1 in hostname_list['sap_landscape'].items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        if k2 == "Severity" and v2 == "The value that you want":
            print(k1) # to print key name of second dict
            print(v1) # to print contents of that dict
```

In this solution, `k1` will be each key of original dictionary while `v1` will be the corresponding values (which is dictionary itself). Then iterating through the items of `v1` will give you each key and value of inner dictionaries. Now you can check whether certain key has a certain value and do what you want.

Comment: @OlvinRoght `"Severity"` is not the key of original dictionary so it will give `None`. But you could use `.get()` with inner v1 dictionary to get the result.

Comment: @rustom garayev thank you very much for your help. have a great week. :)